# one malicious link that is still reflecting on the website

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is a static html site, no cms. no wordpress.
https://www.reternetics.com/

I was running google ads for quite sometime, but now they have disapproved my ads. they say :

> There is one malicious link that is reflecting on the website :
> http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php

I have checked my site offline files 3-4 times, took a new server account & re-uploaded the files (checked files online).
i could not find the malicious link.

The webhost scanned the files for me and no malware detected.

I did an online scan too at:
https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/www.reternetics.com

and it gave no malware found, but gave me the below TLS recommendations.

> HTTPS mixed content found. Your HTTPS website is referring to an HTTP resource:

The 3 paths in HTTPS mixed content found are not there on my server either and neither the malicious link

Now, i uploaded the same files in another url to check:
https://www.reternetics.net/gads/

here, there is no malware & no TLS recommendations for the malicious link:

So, the site is working fine in the alternate url,
but still detects the mal link in my main site https://www.reternetics.com/

Comment: Could you please tell us how you resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I changed my webhosting server, uploaded the same files & then requested Google for a review. My Ad was approved. Then i kept chasing my earlier webhost as my other sites were affected too. They kept giving me all kinds of reasons. But finally they got back to me with a solution and they fixed all my sites. They said they had to do some changes to the domain at the server level, so i do not know what they did, but they fixed the issue for me. hope this helps, my webhost which found the solution is resellerclub.

Comment: thanks for the response I was getting same `sk-jspark_init.php` file response in my website, which is php website without any third party api calling, So I needed to give file permission like 644 to each and every file, js, css and php pages to run on my webhost.

Comment: Shady hosts are the culprits like ResellerClub  (newfold inc, same people behind bigrock, ipages, sitebuilder, web.com, etc) make sure to setup a `ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden` 
 and 404 in htaccess

Answer (score 2):

"Yes that is the server end changes, the server is no longer showing 404 error instead they are showing this page"

- reply from the server team

[image]

Add a 404 redirection and it will be resolved

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
```

Comment: BigRock is the server provider right? I am facing this issue with BigRock cloud hosting. They are showing malicious ads in our website instead of showing error pages.

Comment: No. it's in Hostgator and I think it's happening in CPanel hosting..!!

Comment: For me it doesn't resolved by setting 404 redirection from cpanel, I have to set redirection from .htaccess file. I have hostgator hosting.

Answer (score 1):

It was malicious. It was QUAKbot dropper PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all the links to addresses that don't have https on them like the following:

```
<!-- Social/Contact Links -->
<div class="small text-links">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/reternetics" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

...

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.reternetics.com/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Reternetics">
```

Have a look through your web code and see if this does not resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, i did it today, changed any http to https, but the 3 TLS recommendations still show up at : https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/www.reternetics.com

Comment: what i was saying is that those links :

Comment: are not on my site like : https://www.reternetics.com/.git/HEAD
https://www.reternetics.com/404javascript.js
https://www.reternetics.com/404testpage4525d2fdc

Comment: What I posted above was directly taken from your website, all I did was switch on the browser view page code function. If I can pick it up from your site this means you have to go through your original site files and remove these references in your source.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange but I found the iThemes' security plugin was the culprit!! in a WordPress website. Switching to WordFence ...

Comment: It's not related to WordPress or any pluggin, normal php website also having the issue. We have to explicitly redirect the error pages, else instead of showing error pages, the server showing malware links. Redirect all error pages using htaccess file or using any pluggin. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, it may be- but my case deactivating the iTheme's security plugin solved the issues, Also, one common thing is it is hosted through though webhostbox.net
- means any of the server from endurance brands - https://india.endurance.com/our-brands/

Comment: It's the HOSTING Company! all brands under NEWFOLD (hostgator,bluehost,bigrock,resellerclub,ipage, etc) newfold.com/brands