# Mixed Content: The page at 'url' was loaded over HTTPS

Tags: php

Please help me to resolv this error message. It's my first time to post.

I have deployed my project on Domain am getting this error => Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite_url/form.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have tried too many way to solve it but not work, so how to find the issue please? Thanks.

Comment: Change the URL of the script to use `https:` - `<script src="https://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php">`

Comment: What have you tried exactly? There's only one way to resolve it, which is what Barmar has just said. This has nothing to do with php btw, it's a browser security issue

Comment: Unfortunately, this URL is not in my files. I can't find it.

Comment: I have tried to put this in the meta : <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="block-all-mixed-content">

Comment: The file is the same, only the protocol has been changed from http to https. If that site doesn't support https, it will need to add such support before you can load that file into a https web page

Comment: Your browser is already blocking mixed content (that's what the error message is telling you!) so that policy rule won't change anything

Comment: @ADyson the cpanel on which i host my project is secure so it support https and has a valid certificate.

Comment: Then what exactly does `this URL is not in my files. I can't find it` mean? It's unclear what the problem is, when you switch to using `https://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php` in your code (instead of `http://....etc`.

Comment: @ADyson this URL script : <script src="https://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php"> is not in my files ( not in index.html and not in index.php)

Comment: Well the URL must be referenced somewhere in your page, either as a link or fired from an ajax request. Doesn't the error message in the browser's console you where in the page it came from?

Comment: Google "ks-jspark_init.php" and you'll mentions of it being part of a [malicious WordPress plugin](https://ittone.ma/ittone/javascript-one-malicious-link-that-is-still-reflecting-on-the-website/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [one malicious link that is still reflecting on the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496320/one-malicious-link-that-is-still-reflecting-on-the-website)

Answer (score 0):

Please make your website https.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).