# Deploying ReactJS Application on a Shared Hosting Environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, shared-hosting

I am working on React.js. The application works perfectly on my local machine. However, when I deploy the application, the homepage works fine. But when I refresh the page, a blank screen appears. Upon checking the console, I notice a strange URL that I never used and is not in the code.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'mydomain' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496320/one-malicious-link-that-is-still-reflecting-on-the-website